# How to resolve error: Could not resolve 'interaction.details' from state 'interactions'?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

URL and page are not changing, when I pass id into UI state provider in angularjs.

Here are a few details:

**HTML**

```
<a style="cursor: pointer;" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"  ui-sref="int.details({id:n.id})">Detail</a>
```

**Router**

```
.state('int', {
            url: '/int',
            data: {
                pageTitle: 'Int',
                IsLoginPage: false
            },
            templateUrl: '../../modules/int/views/int.html',
            controller: 'intCtl'
        })
        .state('int.details',{
            url:'/details/{id:id}',
            data: {
                pageTitle: 'Int',
                IsLoginPage: false
            },
            templateUrl: '../../modules/interaction/views/intDetail.html',
            controller:'intCtlDetails',            
        })
```

**Controller**

```
moduleName.controller('intCtlDetails', ["$scope", '$rootScope','$stateParams',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams) {

console.log($stateParams.id);

}]);
```

Comment: any errors on console ?

Comment: no, console is showing blank

Comment: try to add `abstract: true` as property on your int state definition.

Comment: now, i get something in console
Error: Cannot transition to abstract state 'interactions.details'

Comment: You should put it on the first state.. Not the second

Comment: Completely messed

Comment: .state('auth', {
            url: '/login',
            data: {
                pageTitle: 'Login',
                IsLoginPage: true
            },
            templateUrl: '../../modules/login/views/login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'

        })
        .state('forgot-password', {
            url: '/forgot-password',
            templateUrl: 'pages/auth/login.html',
            data: {
                pageTitle: 'Forgot Password',
                IsLoginPage: true
            },
            //controller: 'authCtl'
        })

Comment: have more state above